# Identifying a Math Font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I recently stumbled upon this:

[image]

(From page 13 of [this PDF](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/Elliptic-I.pdf).)

Can anyone identify where the math symbols are coming from? It looks similar to the default LaTeX math font, but it's not quite. The curly braces, in particular, have real curl to them, and the asterisk and angle brackets are also different. I'd like to copy some of these features, if anyone can help me find where they've come from.

Comment: Since the answer to this question is not obvious using the methods in the duplicate question, it seems that the fonts are from the Bakoma TeX versions of the Latin Modern fonts.

Comment: @ChrisS: So how did you find this font information? Perhaps you could add you technique(s) to the linked duplicate...

Comment: @Werner I used the Adobe Reader document properties method, as documented in the accepted answer to the duplicate question, and then Googled the font names until it became apparent that they were from Bakoma TeX. Not magic method, just the standard way and then some Google-fu.